# Applying shadow root to an anchor in Firefox breaks the link

Tags: javascript, firefox, shadow-dom

Here's a basic code:

I have an element

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" id="test">go</a>
```

I do the following to it in Chrome:

```
var a = document.getElementById('test');
var sh = a.createShadowRoot();
sh.textContent = 'GO!!!!!!!';
```

I get the proper behavior, the link text changes to GO!!!!! and I can still click on it.  However, exactly the same behavior in Firefox renders links unusable, unless I attach one more shadowRoot below that one, which is set to a pair of empty content tags.

If anyone encountered this issue, have you guys found a workaround?
Thanks!
Luka

Comment: That's an interesting case. I wonder if it's clearly specified whether this is supposed to work, or not. I wouldn't really have expected it to.

Comment: Well, the inspiration came from  here:  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/  They assign textContent to a button.

Comment: Fair enough: if that doesn't break the button functionality, we might not expect this to break the link functionality. Maybe it'd be worth filing a bug with Mozilla about this.